# How can I store binary values with trailing nulls in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to store fixed width binary data in a numpy array.  However, if my data has trailing nulls, they get stripped.  They do work if I use the void type, but I want to keep them as byte strings.  Is there a way to do this?

```
>>> import numpy as np

# Works
>>> varr = np.array([(b'abc\x00\x00',), (b'de\x00\x00\x00',)], dtype='V5')
[[[97 98 99  0  0]]
 [[100 101   0   0   0]]]

# Strips nulls
>>> sarr = np.array([(b'abc\x00\x00',), (b'de\x00\x00\x00',)], dtype='S5')
[[b'abc']
 [b'de']]
```

Comment: I think the only way to preserve the trailing zeros is to use `void` for "raw data", or to not use `numpy` (which is not that useful anyway if you're dealing with strings). If you need to operate on the byte strings, you could use a `view` into `varr`: `sarr = varr.view('S5')`, but those again do not contain the trailing zeros.

Comment: FYI:  The trailing zeros are actually there in memory, but numpy's convention for the string (`'S'`) format is that any trailing zeros are not considered part of the string.  Take a look at `sarr.view(np.uint8)`.

Answer (score 1):

It dawned on me that I could side-step numpy's processing of the strings by specifying the type as an object.

```
>>> np.array([(b'abc\x00\x00',), (b'de\x00\x00\x00',)], dtype='O')
[[b'abc\x00\x00']
 [b'de\x00\x00\x00']]
```